# Convertir 00:00:00 a 00:00:00 PM / AM

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy trabajando bajo `codeigniter` mi base de datos guarda la hora en `00:00:00` formato de 24hrs lo cual me parece bien, el problema es que para el usuario no es tan rapido de entender como poner un formato de 12hrs un poco mas entendible con AM o PM, asi que queria saber si al momento de mostrar mi hra. se pueda convertir a formatos y como seria.

Comment: No termino de comprender. `00:00:00` y `00:00:00` son la misma hora, ¿no? Si lo que quieres es dar formato a una fecha/hora en PHP, [hay varias preguntas sobre el tema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+formato+hora) que ya tiene respuesta en el sitio.

Comment: ¿podrías agregar el código de tu modelo o controlador? ¿Cuál es tu forma de guardar y mostrar los datos?, sería de mucha ayuda

Comment: simplemente en mi vista lo muestro _<php echo $fecha; ?>_

Comment: No importa en que formato guardes la fecha, la puedes modificar cuando la recuperes, por ejemplo : echo date("g:i:s a",strtotime("18:05:20"));

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba spank!